# Apache POI : power point slides to image draw a black border around elements

Tags: java, apache-poi

I've started playing with apache poi and I was looking at the examples for power point(ppt). What I want is to render a ppt presentation into images.

I've followed the example on their site: http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/how-to-shapes.html#Render  and everything works ok, except that a black border is drawn around each element. 
Is there a way to remove that border?